# image control with radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls

I need a control which can hold an image and two radio buttons, like the one we have when we upload a pictures on fb / orkut.
1. Image
2. Delete radio button.
3. Cover radio button.[Set this image as cover of album]

i have created a user control with these three things.
On my aspx page on click of a button i need to add this user control.
Means, user will select the image using FileUpload and when he clicks on the button this user control should be loaded.
I am able to load the control. Check the following code.

```
<code>
<pre lang="cs">
protected void btnAddURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
   {
//ItemList is an array list used to store the filename.
        ItemList.Add(FileUpload1.FileName);
        showImage();
    }
    }</pre>

    public void showImage()
    {

        PlaceHolder p = new PlaceHolder();

//Create Thumbnail
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"D:\ASP\Project_Dec_16\RealEstate\SaveImage\" +    FileUpload1.FileName);
        System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"D:\ASP\Project_Dec_16\RealEstate\SaveImage\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        System.Drawing.Image bmp2 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        bmp2.Save(@"D:\ASP\Project_Dec_16\RealEstate\SaveImage\thumbnail\L\" + FileUpload1.FileName);

//Load the images selected by user
        for (int i = 0; i &lt;= ItemList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Control MyUserControl;


// Load user control dynamically
                MyUserControl = LoadControl(&quot;MyControl.ascx&quot;);
                    MyUserControl.ID = &quot;MyUserControl&quot; + cnt++;
  // Assign URL
    Image MyImage = (Image)MyUserControl.FindControl("Image1");
                   // MyImage.ID = "Image" + cnt;
                    MyImage.ImageUrl = "~/SaveImage/thumbnail/L/" + ItemList[i].ToString();
   // Add control to panel.
                   p.Controls.Add(MyUserControl);
                    Panel2.Controls.Add(p);

</code>
```

Problem : 
1> All images come on new line i want them next to each other.
2> How to detect which radio button is clicked as i have more than one images, and all have radio buttons.
3> How to capture click of radio button from aspx page?
4> If there is some other way to achieve this let me know.

Searched on google but could not find a solution for this. :( 
Thanks in advance.

[Code After Changes]
in ascx file i have added following code

```
 public event EventHandler rd_ClickDemo;

 protected void deleteimage_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rd_ClickDemo(sender, e);
    }
    protected void setascover_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rd_ClickDemo(sender, e);
    }

In aspx file on click of a button i am doing the following.

 protected void btnAddURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
           // Add file name to array list
            ItemList.Add(FileUpload1.FileName);

          //Add The URL in a text box.
            txtAddURL.Text = txtAddURL.Text + System.Environment.NewLine + System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            //Image1.ImageUrl = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);        
            //this.Button1_Click(this, e);  

            showImage();
        }
    }

public void showImage()
{

        PlaceHolder p = new PlaceHolder();

// Create a Thumbnail Image.
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"D:\ASP\Project_Dec_16\RealEstate\SaveImage\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"D:\ASP\Project_Dec_16\RealEstate\SaveImage\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        System.Drawing.Image bmp2 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        bmp2.Save(@"D:\ASP\Project_Dec_16\RealEstate\SaveImage\thumbnail\L\" + FileUpload1.FileName);

//Load all images from array list.
        for (int i = 0; i <= ItemList.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            // Load user control dynamically
            MyUserControl = LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");

            MyUserControl.ID = "MyUserControl" + cnt++;

          // Find Radio Button
            RadioButton rdb1 = (RadioButton)MyUserControl.FindControl("deleteimage");
            RadioButton rdb2 = (RadioButton)MyUserControl.FindControl("setascover");

            //Attach Group Name.
            rdb1.GroupName = "G1" + cnt.ToString();
            rdb1.ID = "Rb_ID_D" + cnt.ToString();
            rdb1.AutoPostBack = true;
            rdb1.CheckedChanged +=new EventHandler(rdb1_CheckedChanged);

            //Attach Group Name.
            rdb2.GroupName = "G1"+ cnt.ToString();
            rdb2.ID = "Rb_ID" + cnt.ToString();
            rdb2.AutoPostBack = true;
            rdb2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rdb1_CheckedChanged);
            //Image MyImage = (Image)MyUserControl.FindControl("Image1");
            // MyImage.ID = "Image" + cnt;

            //Attach URL to Image.
            Image MyImage = (Image)MyUserControl.FindControl("Image1");
            MyImage.ImageUrl = "~/SaveImage/thumbnail/L/" + ItemList[i].ToString();
            p.Controls.Add(MyUserControl);
            Panel2.Controls.Add(p);
       }
}
```

Still i am not able to trigger the radiobutton_CheckedChanged event.
Please Help.

Comment: looks like you tried to format your code for HTML but you don't need to do so, as StackOverflow's editor is smart enough to do so...

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is your solution for first problem:

1> All images come on new line i want them next to each other.
Ans: You can do so in CSS of your custom control's div block, just set the float to left like this

```
style="display:block;float:right;"
```

2> How to detect which radio button is clicked as i have more than one images, and all have radio buttons. 
Ans: You can get the control which host your RadioButton so u can use NamingContainer property of the Radio button to get the hosting control, which in your case must be you custom control.

3> How to capture click of radio button from aspx page? 
Ans: Do the following in your code:

first when you loop to add You custom control to your Panel2 attach a groupname and a event handler to the RadioButton. (Assuming you already have your radio buttons in your custom control) and then handle the CheckedChanged Event (i am using anonymous delegate for handling event)

```
RadioButton rdb1 = (RadioButton)MyUserControl.FindControl("deleteimage");
RadioButton rdb2 = (RadioButton)MyUserControl.FindControl("setascover");

rd1.GrouprdoSelect2.GroupName = "radiobutton" + i.ToString() ;
rd1.ID = "radiobutton" + i.ToString() + i.ToString() + Convert.ToString(1);
rd1.AutoPostBack = true;
rd1.CheckedChanged += (thesender, ev) => {
       RadioButton rb =  (RadioButton) thesender;
       MyUserControl mcl = rb.NamingContainer as MyUserControl;
       //Perform your task based on the fact of mcl.ID
   }

rd2.GrouprdoSelect2.GroupName = "radiobutton" + i.ToString() ;
rd2.ID = "radiobutton" + i.ToString() + i.ToString() + Convert.ToString(2);
rd2.AutoPostBack = true;
rd2.CheckedChanged += (thesender, ev) => {
       RadioButton rb =  (RadioButton) thesender;
       MyUserControl mcl = rb.NamingContainer as MyUserControl;
       //Perform your task based on the fact of mcl.ID
   }
```